# How to design multiple time clock wise rotation of a image in css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to design a soft button for speed control of a servo through webpage. For this i wand to design a knob which will rotate with mouse click and control speed.

program

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var servoPosition = 1;
servo = document.getElementById('servo');
servo.onclick = function(){
if(servoPosition == 4){
 servoPosition = 1;
}
 else {
servoPosition++;
 }
servo.className = 'rotate position' + servoPosition;
}
</script>
<style>
.back{
position: relative; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.rotate {
 top: 30px;
 left:15px;
 position: absolute; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 2s;
-o-transition-duration: 2s;
transition-duration: 2s;
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;
outline: 0;
}

#servo{
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: gold;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
#servo:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:45%;
  top: 5%;
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.position1{
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
transform:rotate(0deg);
}
.position2{
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
 transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.position3{
-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.position4{
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="rotate" id="servo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

what's wrong with this code?? it creates a knob like structure but did not rotate.

Comment: can you please make snippet of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this?

```js
var servoPosition = 1;
$('#servo').click(function(){
  $('#servo').removeClass('position' + servoPosition);
  if(servoPosition == 4){
    servoPosition = 1;
  }
  else {
    servoPosition++;
  }
  $('#servo').addClass('position' + servoPosition);
})
```

```css
.back{
  position: relative; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rotate {
  top: 30px;
  left:15px;
  position: absolute; 
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}

#servo{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gold;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#servo:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:45%;
  top: 5%;
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.position1{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  transform:rotate(0deg);
}
.position2{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.position3{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.position4{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rotate" id="servo"></div>
```

```js
var servoPosition = 1;
servo = document.getElementById('servo');
servo.onclick = function(){
  if(servoPosition == 4){
    servoPosition = 1;
  }
  else {
    servoPosition++;
  }
  servo.className = 'rotate position' + servoPosition;
}
```

```css
.back{
  position: relative; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.rotate {
  top: 30px;
  left:15px;
  position: absolute; 
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
  -o-transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  outline: 0;
}

#servo{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gold;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#servo:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left:45%;
  top: 5%;
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.position1{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  transform:rotate(0deg);
}
.position2{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
.position3{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.position4{
  -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate" id="servo"></div>
```

Comment: It's not rotating on my computer .would you kindly provide the javascript.

Comment: maybe you dont have jquery, added vanilla js snippet (second one)

Comment: i want to run this code on raspberry pi . installed openjdk-7-jre and openjdk-7-jdk. . Copy paste your program placed all te portion on <style>       and <div> within <body>. but its not rotating the knob. I am not familiar with  java. what mistake i am doing??

Comment: ehm.. not java but javascript. You should follow this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: from your reference all the animations program is running correctly. but this program is not running. it's not rotating.

Comment: try using firefox developer tool for checking errors. If you dont have any errors, check if classes are added to your element

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only four positions, the simplest solution would be to create four CSS classes, one for each position.  So, something like:

```
.rotate1 { /* 90 deg styles */ }
.rotate2 { /* 180 deg styles */ }
.rotate3 { ... }
.rotate4 { ... }
```

Start your knob with one class.  In your onclick function, check which rotate class it currently has, and remove it, and add the next one.

Comment: I need to add an effect to move 90 deg on each click. not 180 deg or 270 deg at a time

Comment: Yes, which is why you have four different styles, that you swap out in sequence.  So, if your knob has `.rotate1`, you swap to `.rotate2`.  If it has `.rotate2`, you swap to `.rotate3`.  The effect will be to rotate around on each click.